# single cluster 2 node datacenter, for replication testing taking 1 node down then i getting error while trying to run the select query in other node

Tags: cassandra

Single cluster 2 node datacenter, for replication testing taking 1 node down then i getting error while trying to run the select query in other node.

Also, the consistency level is ONE and replication factor is 2.

> cassandra@cqlsh> select * from test_telecom.network4G;
>   ServerError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Operation timed out - received only 1 responses.
>
> cassandra@cqlsh> select * from test_telecom.network4G;
>   ServerError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to the previous question - if you have authentication, and using user `cassandra`, that requires `QUORUM` for authentication. And user need to be periodically re-authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

How do you see your CL=ONE? From the second query, it looks like you're query is requesting CL=QUORUM. In that case, you would fail. Quorum of a 2 node cluster is 2. You only have a single node up. Before you run the query, type this into CQLSH:

CONSISTENCY LOCAL_ONE
<...run query again...>

It should work. If you fail to even log into CQL after you take your node down, then the authentication information you're using exists only on the unavailable node (if DSE change system_auth and dse_security to RF > 1, run repair, and re-try).

-Jim